# StarUML - Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, staruml

How do I show an overloaded operator in starUML.

I have overloaded the assignment, equality and array operators. (If that matters)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/staruml/WCr9NZWHjoU) is an answer to your question.

The solution is: edit the name of the operation in the Property editor. All characters are accepted there.